# Why date field is picking the user's timezone?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a date field with default value set to `now`. I have selected the `site's timezone` in the date field settings.

So for every user the date field value should be according to the `site's timezone`. But on node forms I can see the date field value is different for every user according to the timezone set on that user profile form.

Why the field value is not according to the `site's timezone`. it should be same for all the users.

If I disable this settings `Users may set their own time zone` in the regional settings then every thing works fine.

Is there any configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal, dates stored in the DB do not have any timezone fixed to them; it presumes all date fields are consistent in timezone and relies on the system's timezone setting to offset everything to its correct date for displaying.

There are two different offset settings: the field's timezone settings (which adjust from user's timezone input to the site's timezone) & the user's timezone setting which adjust display from the site's timezone to the user's timezone.

Needless to say, the various offset settings can make for a confusing situation to adjust to your needs.

If you want to keep the field adjusted to the site's settings **and** have the users still adjust for their own time zone, you should customize the display of your field so the time zone is presented in an unambiguous format.

Comment: I want the input should be same for all users according to the timezone set for the site. I did not want the input should vary according to the user's timezone.

Comment: What you're asking is kind of vague, but the main reply gets to the heart of the problem (what is being offset and where). I updated the conclusion bas on what you said; if you look at your DB, you'll see all dates are fixed when setting the field to the site's timezone. The issue is how to display the offsetting.

Comment: My requirements are exactly the same according to your answer's last paragraph. so you mean we should just play with the display in the input?